# iPhone - App validation succesful, but loading developer build failed after this

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, provisioning-profile

I created distribution profile and built app with the distribution profile. I have validated the build and the validation is successful.

After this step, i tried to cross verify the app once again and built an app with developer provisioning profile. Archive file is created successfully. But app is failing to install in mobile.

What is the reason behind it.

Comment: Does the provisioning profile have the device UDID?

Comment: Yes. device UDID is in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Did you completely delete the app and reinstall it? Also, is the distribution profile showing up on your device when you look in Xcode's organizer window?

Comment: you see this type of error "'myapp' failed to install". ?

Comment: Yes. I have removed my app on phone. And reinstalled it. And yes, the distribution profile is showing up on my device and it is in verified state.

Comment: Deepesh, yes i am getting "My app" failed to install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you dont have duplicate keys in your keychain. Delete the old ones and create a new key and prov file then everything will work fine. Normally just dupe entries can cause this.

Comment: Thanks.. I have two accounts. Created development provisioning profile  in other account and signed with this provisioning profile in code. My app is launched properly. Only in the above mentioned scenario (My actual question scenario) it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 reason for this error

1) you are not add device UDID in your developer provisioning profile.

2) In your device an app is already install with same developer provisioning profile so the your app is not install in your device.

Comment: My device UDID is in the provisioning profile. Also no other application is there in my device with  the same provisioning profile.